# Como faço um teste unitário utilizando Mockito, para testar a linha : catch (IOExecpetion e)

Tags: java, spring-boot, testes-de-unidade, mockito

Esse é o codigo que quero testar:

```
public String salvarArquivo(final String remessa,
                            final String caminho) {
    final var nomeDoArquivo = DateUtil.formatarLocalDateFromCPB(LocalDate.now());
    final var diretorio = caminho+nomeDoArquivo+TYPE_FILE;
    final var path = Paths.get(diretorio);
    final var charset = StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
    try (var writerBuffer = Files.newBufferedWriter(path, charset)) {
        writerBuffer.write(remessa);
        return diretorio;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.info("IOException: %s%n", e);
    }
    return "Error ao    salvar arquivo";
}
```

E esse é o try que quero que lance a exception

```
try (var writerBuffer = Files.newBufferedWriter(path, charset)) {
        writerBuffer.write(remessa);
        return diretorio;
```

Comment: Você precisa dizer para o Mockito que quando chamar esse método ele lance a exception

Answer (score -1):

Consegui fazendo o mockStatico usando o Mockito da classe Path.class e Files.class, usei tambem o @TempDir para criar arquivos temporário (no final do teste o arquivo é excluido), então o teste ficou assim;

```
@Test
@DisplayName("Deve lançar exceção ErrorRemessaException ao tentar e escrever no BufferdWith")
void salvarArquivo_ParametedInvalid_ThorwExceptionErrorRemessaException(@TempDir Path temDir) throws IOException {

    String remessaTest = "TESTE";
    var path = temDir.resolve("teste.txt");
    var diretorio = path.toString();

    try (MockedStatic<Paths> utilities = Mockito.mockStatic(Paths.class)) {
        try (MockedStatic<Files> filesMockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(Files.class)) {
            filesMockedStatic.when((MockedStatic.Verification) Files.newBufferedWriter(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).thenThrow(IOException.class);

            utilities.when(() -> Paths.get(anyString()))
                    .thenReturn(path);

            assertThatExceptionOfType(ErrorRemessaException.class).isThrownBy(() ->
                    servidorUtil.salvarArquivo(remessaTest, diretorio));
        }
    }
}
```